# Random unzip error when installing pdftron on DevOps build

Tags: angular, npm, azure-pipelines, devops, pdftron

I am trying to install in my pipeline project on DevOps pdftron tool. In order to install this library, I execute this command line: `npx @pdftron/webviewer-downloader --path src/lib --v 8.4.0`

but most of the times (not always) I get the next error:

[image]

I am using a ubuntu-lastest version vm-image and node 14.x version. I have this two questions ([#487](https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-ui/issues/487) and [#499](https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-ui/issues/499)) on github that seems that there was an issue with this tool but It is said, that has been already solved.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to install the WebViewer dependencies using the NPM package?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pdftron/webviewer
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/npm/#1-install-via-npm

We've had this issue before with the another package, and no longer recommend using the download-webviewer script.